# Timeout for db.collection.distinct()?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a database with a collection of about 90k documents. Each document is as follows:

```
{
'my_field_name': "a", # Or "b" or "c" ...
'p1': Array[30], 
'p2': Array[10000]
}
```

There are about 9 unique values for a field name. When there where ~30k documents in the collection:

```
>>> db.collection.distinct("my_field_name")
["a", "b", "c"]
```

However, now with 90k documents, `db.collection.distinct()` returns an empty list.

```
>>> db.collection.distinct("my_field_name")
[]
```

Is there a `maxTimeMS` setting for `db.collection.distinct`? If so how could I set it to a higher value. If not what else could I investigate?

Comment: More likely you are referencing the wrong collection or the wrong field somehow.

Comment: @D.SM 100% sure it isn’t the case. Double checked with a collection of just 3 items

Comment: Try the query in mongo shell.

Comment: Tried in mongo Shell as well. Same result

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: use mydb; db.mycollection.distinct(“my_field_name”); this returns an empty list too

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do to immediately speed up your query's execution time is to index the field on which you are running the 'distinct' operation on (if the field is not already indexed).

That being said, if you want to set a `maxTimeMS`, one work around is to rewrite your query as an aggregation and set the operation timeout on the returned cursor. E.g:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $group: { _id: '$my_field_name' } },
]).maxTimeMS(10000);
```

However unlike `distinct`, a cursor will be returned by the above query.

Comment: Indexing would require `$my_field_name` to be unique for each entry. As mentioned in the question, ~10k documents have the same value for  `$my_field_name`

Comment: Indexing does not have to be unique in MongoDB. You can specify a non-unique index. Unique indexes  are the default but they can be overridden by setting `{unique:False}` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: @newkid as Joe has pointed out, indexes do not have to be unique in MongoDB. Sincerely hope that's not why my answer was down voted. Cheers.

Comment: @IyanuAdelekan, agreed!